# Sylvester matrix without coordinates and its geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, resultant

The (transpose of) the Sylvester matrix of two polynomials $f,g\in A[x]$ represents the following $A$-linear morphism w.r.t the monomial bases of all $A$-algebras involved.

$$\tfrac{A[x]}{\langle g\rangle}\oplus\tfrac{A[x]}{\langle f\rangle}\overset{(u,v)\mapsto uf+vg}{\longrightarrow} \tfrac{A[x]}{\langle fg\rangle}$$

At least over a (possibly multivariate) polynomial ring over a field, I know this $A$-linear map is invertible iff $f,g$ are coprime i.e have no roots in common.

There's an obvious geometric map that behaves the same, at least over a field: $$\mathbf Z(f)\amalg \mathbf Z(g)\longleftarrow \mathbf Z(f)\cup \mathbf Z(g)\subset \mathbb A^1.$$ It's morally clear this map is invertible iff the union is disjoint i.e the intersection is empty i.e $f,g$ have no common root.

By the duality of (a subcategory of?) rings and a (subcategory of?) affine scheme, I'd expect the latter, that is very canonical in geometry, to come from some $A$-algebra morphism. But it does not seem to be the one represented by the Sylvester matrix, since $(1,v)\mapsto f+vg,(u,1)\mapsto uf+g$ and the product $(u,v)\mapsto uf+vg$ which is not (I think) the product of the values $(f+vg)(uf+g)=uf^2+vg^2\in \tfrac{A[x]}{\langle fg\rangle}$.

**Questions.** What am I missing? What is the geometric interpretation of the linear map represented by the (transpose of) the Sylvester matrix w.r.t the monomial bases?

Comment: You shouldn't expect $\langle fg \rangle$ to (scheme-theoretically) cut out $Z(f) \cup Z(g)$ if $f$ and $g$ share roots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first map you wrote down isn't a ring homomorphism (already it doesn't send $1$ to $1$), so it doesn't have an algebro-geometric interpretation. The obvious ring homomorphism goes in the other direction, namely what you might call the "Chinese remainder theorem map"

$$A[x]/(fg) \ni p \mapsto (p \bmod f, p \bmod g) \in A[x]/f \times A[x]/g$$

given by the two obvious projections. Now there is a corresponding morphism of affine schemes going in the other direction from what you wrote, namely the canonical map $Z(f) \sqcup Z(g) \to Z(fg)$.

This map does not seem to me to have any obvious relationship to the Sylvester matrix. In the standard treatment of resultants you will see the domain of the Sylvester map being given as polynomials of degrees $< \deg f$ and $< \deg g$, rather than as elements of the quotients $A[x]/f, A[x]/g$; note that these quotients are not free $A$-modules on the monomial basis unless the leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are invertible over $A$.

However in a suitable basis the determinant of the Chinese remainder map is also the resultant (up to scale or something), since this determinant shares the same property the resultant does that it vanishes iff the polynomials have a common root, and the resultant as a polynomial is known to be irreducible. So this leads to an alternative definition of the resultant.

Some details. It seems fairly annoying to write down the Chinese remainder map in the monomial basis, but we can use the following alternative basis: if $\deg f = n$ and $\deg g = m$, and assuming WLOG that $n \le m$, we can use the basis $\{ 1, x, x^2, \dots x^{n-1}, f, fx, fx^2, \dots fx^{m-1} \}$ of $A[x]/(fg)$ (assuming for simplicity that the leading coefficient of $f$ is invertible over $A$). Then the map to $A[x]/f$ is easy to describe since it just sends this basis to $1, x, x^2, \dots x^{n-1}, 0, 0, \dots$. The map to $A[x]/g$ also just sends $\{1, x, x^2, \dots x^{n-1} \}$ to those same monomials but the later terms depend on the coefficients of $fx^k \bmod g$. The resulting $(n+m) \times (n+m)$ matrix has an upper left block which is just the identity matrix so its determinant ends up being the determinant of the $m \times m$ lower right block, consisting of the coefficients of $fx^k \bmod g$. The claim that this recovers the resultant appears as Theorem 1.18 [here](http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN5.pdf) but I don't know if it has a name or who it's due to. It may be related to the [Bezout matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_matrix).

Here's an explicit calculation for $n = m = 2$ with monic polynomials. If we write $f(x) = x^2 + f_1 x + f_0$ and $g(x) = x^2 + g_1 x + g_0$ then the ordinary resultant coming from the Sylvester matrix is

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{Res}(f, g) &=& \det \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & f_1 & f_0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & f_1 & f_0 \\ 1 & g_1 & g_0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & g_1 & g_0 \end{array} \right] \\
 &=& (f_1 - g_1)(f_1 g_0 - f_0 g_1) + (f_0 - g_0)^2. \end{eqnarray*}$$

The Chinese remainder map, on the other hand, with respect to the bases $\{ 1, x, f, fx \}, \{ 1, x \}, \{ 1, x \}$ as above, is given by

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & f_0 - g_0 & -(f_1 - g_1) g_0 \\ 0 & 1 & f_1 - g_1 & -(f_1 - g_1) g_1 + (f_0 - g_0) \end{array} \right]$$

and its determinant reduces to a $2 \times 2$ determinant which, after some simplification, coincides with the resultant. If we allowed leading coefficients there would be some denominators, I guess.

Comment: Cool. In other words, some row-reduction on the Sylvester matrix gives the block matrix you describe, and the lower right block represents the operator multiplication by $g$ on $A[x]/\langle f\rangle $, right?

Comment: @Arrow: I didn't say that; maybe something like that is true but I don't see it (the obvious first step of row reduction on the Sylvester matrix above produces a term $f_0 - f_1^2$ which doesn't appear anywhere in the Chinese remainder matrix). The lower right block represents multiplication by $f$ on $A[x]/g$.

Comment: Conceptually an element of the kernel of the Sylvester map is a pair $p, q$ of polynomials of degrees $\le \deg f, \deg g$ such that $pf + qg = 0$. On the other hand an element of the kernel of the Chinese remainder map is a single polynomial $r$ which is divisible by both $f$ and $g$. These things are related but they aren't the same and I don't see how to get from one to the other via a *linear* transformation.

Comment: It makes me think of gcd vs lcm (kernel of Chinese remainder map). But if you don't see, I definitely won't... At any rate, how get from one to the other nonlinearly?

Comment: I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780380/223002) which in a sense motivated this one originally.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm just being silly: if $pf + qg = 0$ then the common value of $pf = -qg$ is a polynomial which is divisible by both $f$ and $g$. Conversely if $r$ is such a polynomial then we can take $p = \frac{r}{f}, q = - \frac{r}{g}$. So I guess there ought to be a way to do it after all.

Comment: You mentioned getting from one to another via a *linear* transformation above, but I don't see it. I don't see how to fill the gap. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Arrow: the linear transformations are given by $(p, q) \mapsto pf = -qg$ and $r \mapsto \left( \frac{r}{f}, - \frac{r}{g} \right)$. These are linear in $(p, q)$ resp. $r$, with coefficients depending on the coefficients of $f, g$.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about linear maps between the kernels! I thought there was sort of relation between the maps themselves. The linear maps you describe mean the Sylvester map and the CRT map are simultaneously injective?

Comment: Also, Sylvester map is $A$-linear, so at least if $f,g$ are monic it's a morphism of finite free $A$-modules. In geometry that should be something like a morphism of vector bundles, so shouldn't there be a visualization after all?

Comment: I guess, but that's quite different from what you asked about in terms of $Z(f)$ and $Z(g)$.